# How acess a function from another component without using JSX

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying **call a function** from  **another component function**.

Inside **SceneManager**, componentDidMount() I'm trying to call a function in **HUD_Html**, enableViewItem()

SceneManager Component.

```
componentDidMount() {


    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    //Call function here
    //
    HUD_Html.enableViewItem("photo1") //e.g
 }
 render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)}>
        <HUD_Html/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

}

HUD_Html Component

```
enableViewItem = (imagesNames) =>{
    //DO MY CODE
}
```

I tried with props, states and another examples in internet... but without sucess.

I guess with 'ref' this will work... but they said that isn't recommended... there's another way to do it?

I'm not using events on jsx render because I'm using threeJS canvas to make triggers

Comment: You could make `enableViewItem` a `static` function, if you don't need access to `this` inside it

Comment: Why not do this the reactive way? Place the 'enabled view items' in the state of the SceneManager component and pass it through props to the HUD_Html component.

Comment: I need use `this` to acess internal variables.
How I place `enabledViewItems` in state SceneManager? I place the function or the reference?

Comment: It is uncommon to access properties or functions of a child component, as it is usually not needed. Therefore I assume that they say that using ref is not recommended. However, ref is there for a reason, and if it works for you, using ref is the way to go. Furthermore as far as I am aware there is no (proper) way to access properties or functions of another component directly other than by using ref.

What logic does `enableViewItem` contain?

Comment: I see. I'm learning react about 2 months, I was finding for others possible ways, but in the end I used `ref`. 
`SceneManager` is a canvas with **ThreeJS**. So, when the **player** colider with a chest I'll show up a HUD with the itens.
There's no click interaction, it's a trigger from canvas 3D (position 3D) to a Html interface with images and text to show.
With ThreeJS I can't work with `render()` triggers properties (I guess). That's why I need to send trigger from function in `SceneManager`.
`enableViewItem` will receive this trigger with params and will show it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add export statement:

```
export const enableViewItem = imagesNames => {
    //DO MY CODE
}
```

And call it in the your another component.

Comment: I see. But I need to put it on top out of my class. There's a way to acess the internal variable of my class?

Comment: Make it static. Or call with new instance of class where this functions is present: new ClassName().enableViewItem(...);